# Rolling dates in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQIWE.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBNfs.jpg)I have the following data frame. I am trying to group the data into rolling date categories based on the received date. I need this code to work so that when a new piece of data is added to the source, it still falls into these date groups: 0-3 months, 3-6 months, 6-9, 9-12, and 12+. Can someone please walk me through how to do this? I have searched high and low for days and I just don't understand how to do it. I have tried grouping the dates based on receive date but that doesn't account for new dates being added (picture attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHwM1.jpg). My ultimate goal is to deploy this in a dash app. I have a ton of other graphs that are currently deployed but I have a handful that have to use the datetime buckets and I can't do them until I figure this part out.

Comment: "for new dates being added" -- well, there's no automatic trigger to force this.  When you change the dataframe, you'll need to recompute the new columns.  It shouldn't take very long.

Comment: I must not have explained this well. I want to create buckets or bins using that are something like: current date - 90 days, 90 days - 180 days, etc. so that when the source CSV is updated it will work.

Comment: No, I get it.  Are you just asking how to adjust the grouping commands in your second image so they use today's date?  If that's all you want, that's easy.

Comment: I've added more pictures. I'm trying to create bins such as the ones in the first picture but I keep getting a TypeError that I don't know how to work around. When I first posted this question I didn't even know how to get to this point but I figured it out yesterday.

Comment: Pictures is not the right way.  You should be adding these as text blocks, not as images, and when you edit your question, you need to add text saying that you added it and why.  You're just making it harder on US.  Your error says that you're comparing a numpy datetime64 to a Python date variable.  It's easy to convert a date to a numpy datetime64.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so that's the only way it lets me add pictures right now. Not trying to make it harder on you, sorry my bad. Still trying to get the hang of using Stackoverflow. I figured it out myself anyway but thank you for trying.